# Left join with subqueries returning null

Tags: mysql, subquery, left-join

I'm stuck with something that I cant figure out how to solve it. There is 3 Tables Locations, Models, User_Likes. I want to get most liked models in some country and countries cities.

Table Locations

```
Loc_ID, Top_ID, Name, Perma
```

Table Model

```
Model_ID, Phone, Loc_ID
```

Table User_Likes

```
Model_ID, User_ID, Date
```

Example data:

Locations:

```
1 | NULL | USA      | usa
2 | NULL | Germany  | germany
3 | 1    | New York | new-york
4 | NULL | Rusia    | rusia
```

Models:

```
Seda    |   11  |   1
Zelda   |   33  |   2
Dilara  |   22  |   3
```

User_Likes

```
Seda    |   1   |   0
Seda    |   2   |   0
Zelda   |   1   |   0
Dilara  |   1   |   0
```

My Query

```
SELECT U.Model_ID, M.Loc_ID, M.Name, M.Top_ID, M.Perma, COUNT(*) FROM User_Likes as U  
    LEFT JOIN ( SELECT Model.ID, Model.Loc_ID, Yer.Name, Yer.Top_ID, Yer.Perma From Model
        LEFT JOIN (SELECT Locations.Loc_ID, Locations.Name, Locations.Top_ID, Locations.Perma FROM Locations WHERE Locations.Loc_ID = ? OR Locations.Top_ID = ? ) as Yer ON Model.Loc_ID = Yer.Loc_ID ) 
        as M  ON M.ID = U.Model_ID
GROUP BY U.Model_ID
```

Results:

```
? = 1

Seda    |  1    |   USA         |   NULL    | usa | 2
Zelde   |  3    |   New York    |   1       | new-york | 2
```

This part is okay but problem starts over here

```
? = 4
Seda    |  1    |   NULL        |   NULL    | NULL | 2
Zelde   |  3    |   NULL    |   NULL        | NULL | 2
```

result over here needs to be empty

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this query you don't need those inner select queries

```
SELECT U.Model_ID,
 M.Loc_ID,
 M.Name,
 M.Top_ID,
 M.Perma, 
COUNT(*) FROM User_Likes as U  
    LEFT JOIN  Model M ON M.ID = U.Model_ID
        LEFT JOIN Locations L ON M.Loc_ID = L.Loc_ID WHERE L.Loc_ID = ? OR L.Ust_ID = ? GROUP BY U.Model_ID
```

Comment: please check this and let me know

Comment: There is so much problems with this query for example there is no L alias or M

Comment: its a small typo please check now

Comment: I mean like its okay but please correct me if I'm wrong this query counts all of the models likes and after that narrow it down with select is it the best solution

Comment: join will perform better than inner select queries and please execute and check this you are getting the correct result set

Comment: Oh, sorry I already checked it. It works, my only suspision about this query is counting whole like data please think this in like 1 milion  dataset Isn't it will be slow because It's counting every single like and after checking the location cant we count just that location's models like

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/116125/discussion-between-mahesh-madushanka-and-sarp-aykent).